# Https request with csrftoken not working well

Tags: node.js, https, csrf-token

I need to fetch some information from public url that should allow me to fetch data by the law but it seems I dont sure how to do it.

In the browser I just need to log in with public username (that wrote on the site itself for all) then it redirect me to the desired page.

(**it works for me with puppteer library but I want to learn how to do it with out puppteer)

I saw when i send a request from the browswer the payload is

```
r: 
username: myUserName
password: 
Submit: Sign in
csrftoken: lA7yNotQsQbfi-TmDMLEZYGP5_SGEjjLb3T3Dkgd4N4
```

So , I tried some hardcoded and copy the request headers from the browser network traffic to the request header with https request as follow:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'url.retail.publishedprices.co.il',
  path: '/login/user',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
  //the hardcoded header include the cookie already, just paste it for show u key,value
     ...hardCodedHeaders , 
    'Cookie': 'cftpSID=Rd3jMOMVGybEd9SynV7C0SoyOZbYhTy7xT37lXtQiTs',
  }
};

const postData = 'r=&username=myUserName&password=&Submit=Sign+in&csrftoken=WB7r8qlnLafDZAA3mSc3b-DKdoRudzgX-zelu7P3y7s';

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  if (res.statusCode >= 300 && res.statusCode <= 399 && res.headers.location) {
    // Redirect response, follow the redirect
    https.get(res.headers.location, (res2) => {
      let data = '';
      res2.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      res2.on('end', () => {
      // the desired content of the redirected page but actuly i got  error
        console.log(data); 
      });
    });
  } else {
    let data = '';
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log(data); // the content of the response page
    });
  }
});

req.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

I tried some different approch , all end with same error:

```
Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: myUrl. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.myUrlPart2, DNS:myUrlPart2
```

What i'm missing here? (also , i dont want use hardcoded for the csrftoken and the cftpSID , how do i get them ?)

** i also tried using rejectUnauthorized = false but it send me the current login page as the response